# Can I use raw sql insert or update in Sails?

Tags: sql, sails.js, waterline

According to the documentation, http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/query.html, I'm able to use query() method to use native sql 'queries', but I'm confused whether insert or update is considered as 'queries' because some people use the term 'queries' to mean insert or update in sql.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `query()` method will send the raw SQL

Comment: not only SELECT, querying from existing table, but also inserting a new row?

Comment: Yes, the ```query()``` method will send raw SQL, any SQL that is compatible with your adapter.